# Solid Geometry. Finding an angle

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

$\mathrm{AB}=10$ and it intersects plane a. $\mathrm{A}$ and $\mathrm {B}$ are $2\mathrm{m}$ and $3\mathrm{m}$ far from the plane and the question is to find angle formed by plane a and $\mathrm{AB}$.

I get it that I can use tangent to find the angle but I only know one side of the both triangles, so how could I approach this problem?

Comment: You know the hypotenuse, $10$, and the opposite side, $2+3=5$. That's enough to find the angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, let the line $AB$ intersect the plane at point $O$ & $AM=2$ & $BN=3$ be the perpendiculars drawn  to the plane from the points $A$ & $B$ respectively then  $\triangle AMO$  & $\triangle BNO$ are similar right triangles so one should have 
$$\frac{AM}{BN}=\frac{AO}{OB}\ \ \ \ \  \left(\triangle AMO\sim \triangle BNO\right)$$
$$\frac{2}{3}=\frac{AO}{OB}$$
$$\frac{2}{3}+1=\frac{AO}{OB}+1$$
$$\frac{5}{3}=\frac{AO+OB}{OB}$$
$$\frac{5}{3}=\frac{AB}{OB}$$
$$\frac{5}{3}=\frac{10}{OB}\ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \left(\text{given}, \ \ \ AB=10\right)$$
$$\implies OB=6$$

If $\theta$ is the angle between plane & the line $AB$ then, in right $\triangle BNO$, 
$$\sin\theta=\frac{BN}{OB}=\frac{3}{6}=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\theta=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=30^\circ$$